# Can't run raw git filter-branch

Tags: python, git, shell, git-filter-branch, gitpython

I'm using git-python in one of my projects, and currently I have this code:

```
tpl = """
    if test $GIT_COMMIT = "%s"; then
        export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="%s"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="%s"
    fi
"""

s = ""
for commit in filter(lambda x: x["newdatetime"] is not None, self.commit_datetime):
    s += tpl % (
        commit["hash"],
        commit["newdatetime"].replace(tzinfo = None),
        commit["newdatetime"].replace(tzinfo = None)
    )
cmd = "'%s'" % s
cmd = re.compile("(?<=')\s+(?=\S)").sub("", cmd)
cmd = re.compile("(?<=\S)\s+(?=')").sub("", cmd)
self.git.repo.git.filter_branch("-f", "--env-filter \\\n", cmd)
```

For the sake of this question, accept that the result of the lambda function is an array of a single element with the following data:

```
{
    "hash": "random git hash",
    "newdatetime": "datetime string parseable by git filter branch"
}
```

The 2 `re` commands are used to strip trailing and leading empty spaces before and after the first/last `'` character.

The final result is:

```
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(1)
cmdline: git filter-branch -f --env-filter \
'if test $GIT_COMMIT = "64436207f36dd78e128936bbdec16b8741ff418c"; then
         export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="2017-07-24 18:56:26"
         export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2017-07-24 18:56:26"
fi'
stderr: 'usage: git filter-branch [--env-filter <command>] [--tree-filter <command>]
    [--index-filter <command>] [--parent-filter <command>]
    [--msg-filter <command>] [--commit-filter <command>]
    [--tag-name-filter <command>] [--subdirectory-filter <directory>]
    [--original <namespace>] [-d <directory>] [-f | --force]
    [<rev-list options>...]'
```

The command seems to be fine, and running it in a shell works as expected, just fine. Either git-python is doing something funky or I'm missing a (probably) very simple error. Which one is it?

EDIT:

I updated the code, so now it looks like:

```
tpl = """
    if [ "$GIT_COMMIT" == "%s" ]; then
        export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="%s";
        export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="%s";
    fi
"""
...
...
self.repo.git.filter_branch("-f", "--env-filter", cmd)
```

And now I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexandernst/Proyectos/git-rewrite-date/git_rewrite_date.py", line 135, in rewrite
    self.mygit.rewrite_dates(commits)
  File "/Users/alexandernst/Proyectos/git-rewrite-date/my_git.py", line 38, in rewrite_dates

    self.repo.git.filter_branch("-f", "--env-filter", cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 425, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: self._call_process(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 877, in _call_process
    return self.execute(call, **exec_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 688, in execute
    raise GitCommandError(command, status, stderr_value, stdout_value)
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(1)
  cmdline: git filter-branch -f --env-filter 'if [ "$GIT_COMMIT" == "0694755bb844e5b5a569b56ee5154232265ccfe6" ]; then
        export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="2017-07-24 22:43:54";
        export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2017-07-24 22:43:54";
fi'
Rewrite 8cbb2c9143ed58722d001b5c4f0e801636dbd079 (1/25) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    '
  stderr: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-filter-branch: line 354: if [ "$GIT_COMMIT" == "0694755bb844e5b5a569b56ee5154232265ccfe6" ]; then
        export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="2017-07-24 22:43:54";
        export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2017-07-24 22:43:54";
fi: command not found
env filter failed: 'if [ "$GIT_COMMIT" == "0694755bb844e5b5a569b56ee5154232265ccfe6" ]; then
        export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="2017-07-24 22:43:54";
        export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2017-07-24 22:43:54";
fi''
```

Note that I do get some progress in there, where it says "Rewrite 8cbb2.... (1/25)". That means that it's actually running the command, but then it fails for some odd reason.

Comment: Side comment: there's no need to call `re.compile` directly; all the operations on a compiled expression can be invoked on a string, e.g., `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this in my own project using `subprocess` and the bash syntax you have in your update (with semicolons and square brackets).

Maybe it's just the added `.strip()` on my multi-line string that fixed it?

Here is the raw code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def set_commit_date(repo_dir: str, commit: str, new_date: str):
    command = [
        '/usr/bin/git', 'filter-branch', '--env-filter',
        f"""
        if [ $GIT_COMMIT = {commit} ];
        then
            export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="{new_date}";
            export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="{new_date}";
        fi
        """.strip()
    ]
    process = Popen(command, cwd=repo_dir, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

    result, error = process.communicate()
    if error:
        raise Exception(error.decode())

    print(result.decode())
    print(repo_dir)
    print(commit)
    print(new_date)
```

When I run this against a dummy repo in my unit tests I get the following output (success) from the following args:

```
Rewrite 1f05fc01ffc790f5a32a918a0149f5096b5edaac (1/1) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    
Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten

/tmp/tmp7zzep_dz/testrepo

1f05fc01ffc790f5a32a918a0149f5096b5edaac

Sun, 03 Sep 2017 00:00:00 -0400
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is in `"--env-filter \\\n"`. I think the command should just be

```
self.git.repo.git.filter_branch("-f", "--env-filter", cmd)
```

Comment: I'm getting some progress with that. Now I see `'fi': command not found` error. Any ideas?

Comment: I added second answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also think `subprocess` (used deep in GitPython) make this

```
tpl = """
    if test $GIT_COMMIT = "%s"; then
        export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="%s"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="%s"
    fi
"""
```

one line. So you need to correct bash syntax in case there are no newlines:

```
tpl = """
    if test $GIT_COMMIT = "%s"; then
        export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="%s";
        export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="%s";
    fi
"""
```

(add `;` in place of newlines).

Comment: I still get `fi: command not found`. My gut tells me there is some wrong bash (or whatever interpretor `subprocess` is using) syntax in there, but I can't spot it.